# How do I nest this group?

Tags: sql

My code, the instructions "***List the number of parts on hand by classification within each warehouse***"

```
    SELECT Warehouse, Class, Sum(OnHand) AS [Number of Parts]
    FROM Part
    Group BY Warehouse,Class
```

The warehouses are always separated, I want it to have each warehouse and a the list inside
inside, instead it repeats the warehouse 
http://s16.postimg.org/golxkcdid/Untitled_1.jpg

Structure
http://postimg.org/image/6exnykeod/

Comment: Provide us the structure of the table...

Comment: Im new to sql but by structure what more information do you need ? Thank You

Comment: I think the 'group' you're probably expecting is something that should be done in the application, not in sql.

Comment: The structure of a table is the description of the columns, the type, etc...

Comment: Could you edit your question with the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably do what you want but this would better be done in an Access 'report', not the query itself.

```
select v.warehouse, p.class, sum(p.onhand) as [Number of Parts]
  from part as p
  left outer join (select warehouse, min(class) as class
                     from part
                    group by warehouse) as v
    on p.warehouse = v.warehouse
   and p.class = v.class
 order by p.warehouse, p.class
```

To format the results using an Access report -- which would be the standard approach -- you can find instructions here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA010006894.aspx

Comment: Seem too far ahead too what we've learned in class , I just want to be able to satisfy this question "List the number of parts on hand by classification within each warehouse"

Comment: @JDMshifter your query does exactly that. If you want to "break on" warehouse then you would normally do that in an Access report. This is not something that anyone would normally do in sql, at least not plain sql. In Oracle for instance you could break on warehouse and specify no duplicates, using sqlplus, but that is a matter of formatting. Your question relates to formatting the query results, not the query results. In Access, you format query results using Access reports.

Comment: @JDMshifter your question was about sql and this answer returns exactly the expected result. We are not here to do your homework for you! Try to find the solution by yourself with the stuff you've learn instead of choosing the easiest way here (cheating will not help you for the future exam...)